# why an URL appears in my query results using the SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, ontology

The query that is in the picture is done using the SPARQL and Protege, it is used to retrieve the phases names but an URL appear beside the name how can I remove this URL? Or is there any mistake found in the query that makes this happen?

[query and result's picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M056G.png)

Comment: 1. don't post anything here as pictures hosted by 3rd party

Comment: 2. that URL is the datatype of the literal. each literal in RDF (1.1) has such a datatype, if you don't want this, use [`str`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-str) function of SPARQL to get the lexical form of the literal, e.g.`SELECT (str(?budgetPhase1Name) as ?var1) ... WHERE ...`

Comment: @AKSW Thank you so much for your attention and the useful answer for me . could you tell me if i want to retrieve an integer value ,should i use an integer function because i tried it and an url appears also in the query result?

Comment: @AKSW may i ask you if there any query in the SPARQL that can be used to add 2 numbers(integer or long data types )? thank u in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The literal values you are retrieving are [typed literals](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-rdf11-concepts-20140225/#section-Datatypes).
As @AKSW commented, use the STR() function to get the untyped lexical form.

Comment: Please i want to know if i want to retrieve an integer number and when i made the query also an url appear . so what shall i do ?

Comment: please tell me this

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with it. Perhaps best asked as a separate question. You should show your new query with sample data and describe what you want to do with the result. What your retrieving is an integer and you can do integer arithmetic with it in your query.

Comment: for example i want to retrieve phase_no = 1 it already done but beside the number there is an url , so how can i remove it

Comment: @SohaAhmed The same way, use `str`.